# Cannot retrieve all 2D array data from Java properties file

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to get 2D array data from a Java properties file and store these data into a HashMap object.The thing that makes me puzzled is that Eclipse only retrieves only some of the data from the 2D array.

Here are the codes:

```
Properties config = new Properties();
config.load(new FileInputStream("categories.properties"));
String[][] categories = fetchArrayFromPropFile("content", config);
HashMap<String,Integer> hashmap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
for (String[] mapping : categories)
{
  hashmap.put(mapping[0], 0);
}
```

---

```
private static String[][] fetchArrayFromPropFile(String propertyName, Properties propFile) {
  String[] a = propFile.getProperty(propertyName).split(";");
  String[][] array = new String[a.length][a.length];
  for(int i = 0;i < a.length;i++) {
    array[i] = a[i].split(",");
  }
  return array;
}
```

In categories.properties file:

```
content=Advertising,0;Agriculture,0;Art,0;Automotive,0;Aviation,0;Banking,0;Beverages,0;Biotechnology,0;Business,0;Crime,0;Disasters,0;Economics,0;Education,0;Elections,0;Fashion,0;Food,0;Hardware,0;Health,0;Hotels,0;Intellectual Property,0;Investing,0;Labor,0;
Law,0;Marriage,0;Mobile Devices,0;Politics,0;Real Estate,0;Renewable Energy,0;Robotics,0;Science,0;Social Media,0;Software and Internet,0;Space,0;Sports,0;Technology,0;Traditional Energy,0;Travel,0;Video Games,0;War,0;Weather,0;Entertainment,0;No Topic,0; Business_Finance,0;Disaster_Accident,0;Entertainment_Culture,0;Environment,0;Health_Medical_Pharma,0;Hospitality_Recreation,0;Human  Interest,0;Law_Crime,0;Religion_Belief,0;Technology_Internet,0;War_Conflict,0;Other,0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your property file format is

> ```
> content=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
> XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
> ```

You see, **it is split into two lines for one property. So when reading your content property, it reads only the first line and all data are not contained.**

If so, please concatenated your property file into one line manually like this.

```
content=Advertising,0;Agriculture,0;Art,0;Automotive,0;Aviation,0;Banking,0;Beverages,0;Biotechnology,0;Business,0;Crime,0;Disasters,0;Economics,0;Education,0;Elections,0;Fashion,0;Food,0;Hardware,0;Health,0;Hotels,0;Intellectual Property,0;Investing,0;Labor,0;Law,0;Marriage,0;Mobile Devices,0;Politics,0;Real Estate,0;Renewable Energy,0;Robotics,0;Science,0;Social Media,0;Software and Internet,0;Space,0;Sports,0;Technology,0;Traditional Energy,0;Travel,0;Video Games,0;War,0;Weather,0;Entertainment,0;No Topic,0; Business_Finance,0;Disaster_Accident,0;Entertainment_Culture,0;Environment,0;Health_Medical_Pharma,0;Hospitality_Recreation,0;Human  Interest,0;Law_Crime,0;Religion_Belief,0;Technology_Internet,0;War_Conflict,0;Other,0;
```

If so, your code works fine and all data are read.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
String[][] array = new String[a.length][2];
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.The output on the console is like this: Advertising,0;Agriculture,0;Art,0;Automotive,0;Aviation,0;Banking,0;Beverages,0;Biotechnology,0;Business,0;Crime,0;Disasters,0;Economics,0;Education,0;Elections,0;Fashion,0;Food,0;Hardware,0;Health,0;Hotels,0;Intellectual Property,0;Investing,0;Labor,0; (Not all of the data is retrieved)

Comment: And have you inserted a debug statement to verify that the entire properties string is being read in before the splits?

Comment: swemon solved the problem already,but thank you for trying to help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use "\" to connect diffident lines for one property.

For example:

```
  a=b \
    c
```